# Is every day Coffee Day?

Tags: discussion, coffee

I heard recently that every day is Coffee Day, but then it was pointed out to me that this only happens once a year; can someone please clarify this for me?

**Is every day Coffee Day?**

Comment: "in the absence of any moderation, the community would do nothing but add and upvote the easy, fun stuff..." ([The Trouble With Popularity](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/))

Comment: Off-topic. This should be migrated to [coffee.se].

Comment: @ChristianRau can meta Q's *be* migrated? Feel free to cross post

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I haven't had my morning coffee yet.

Answer (score 10):

I think your confusion results from the misunderstanding the criteria: *only days ending in "day"* are coffee days.

This is how coffee day is determined. Any other days do not count.

Answer (score 10):

As a devoted Coffeeist, I can only say that the tradition of Coffee Day is far too powerful for one single day, possibly too great for an entire year! I think we all know the answer to this question, we know it in our gut, and we know it in our heart.

As sure as the sun will rise every day, so will the coffee in our cups. Have a Happy Coffee Day everyone, and have it every day.

Comment: I know it in my heart, too. I have hypertension! :)

Answer (score 6):

As the creator of [Coffee Day](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/21?m=22762314#22762314), I can canonically tell you that ***Yes, every day is Coffee Day***.

Comment: This answer commits the "appeal to authority" logical fallacy. Can you present any _evidence_ in support of your claim?

Comment: I drink, therefore I am. The rest is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 6):

I love hot meta posts.  Coffee is hot.  In conclusion it is coffee day.

Comment: +1E6 for a post that finally makes sense of this whole thing.

Comment: @GlenH7 NO! NO IE6! Bad!

Comment: @durron597 - clearly, you ***need some more coffee.***  Because that's the number one ("1") and not the letter "i".

Answer (score 5):

This statement is **incredibly inaccurate** and whoever pointed its incorrectness out to you is absolutely right (not to say an utter genius!).

As can be read on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Coffee_Day) the official *International Coffee Day* is on a specific set date. So depending on where you live, you still have to wait a few weeks with any celebrations.

Comment: You would tell me I can't have coffee for *weeks*!?! Begone foul demon!

Comment: who downvoted? if we want this in Hot Meta Posts, _every_ answer should be voted up not down

Answer (score 5):

[image: Coffee Stack Exchange]

<sub><sub>(thanks to MichaelT for pointing to [appropriate ad](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7177/31260))</sub></sub>

Comment: To be fair, that looks utterly delicious